# Delete fixed string contained in SQL Server Table Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dirty-data

I have a table with filed 'myData' of type nvarchar containing sometimes a data ending with the string '|||' that I want to remove.
Obviously the data is not fixed, so I can't just use

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myData = REPLACE(myData, 'oldString', 'newString')
```

as this would work just for one record (e.g. `oldString = '12-feb-17|||' and newString = '12-feb-17'`)

How can I do it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET myData = LEFT(myData, LEN(myData) - 3)
    WHERE myDATE LIKE '%|||';
```